# Discarding the volatile qualifier in a later part of the C code

Tags: c, arm, embedded, llvm

I have the following code construct

```
int foo( volatile int *a)
{
     if(*a != VALID)
     {
          // suspend for few seconds 
          suspend();
          // check  again
          if(*a != VALID)
          {
               //error. data was unavailable 
               return -1; 
          }
     }
     // cast away the volatile. Does not accept volatile
     call_external_interface((int*)a) ; 

     return 0;
}
```

Here the memory location pointed by "a" is filled in from an external source(via DMA transfer).

Once it is available the buffer is pointed by "a" is processed via an external interface call that does not accept "volatile", hence the casting away the "volatile".

The assumption is that the "volatile" needed only until the buffer is filled by the external resource, so the memory location is checked twice whether the data is available or not ( and instructions are not discarded since it is declared volatile).

The assumption is also that once the buffer is available, it is just processed internally, so the volatile can be discarded.

Can i be sure that the "call_external_interface" is called only after executing the instructions coded before it? Do i need an explicit memory barrier?

The processor can do out of order execution.

Any other remarks on how to make this code safe?

Comment: In theory, re-ordering of volatile access is forbidden by the C standard. In practice, the compiler might just leave it to the CPU to do as it pleases and put the burden of C compliance on the application programmer. You should probably mention which instruction set and compiler this is.

Comment: The compiler is LLVM8 and the instruction set is ARMv7a.

Comment: Is it safe to cast away the "volatile"   once the buffer has been filled and has been verified?. Perhaps i can do a objDump and check if that is case.

Comment: The catch is that volatile may or may not guarantee memory barrier behavior on the given system. I don't know this system, so I can't say. Apart from that, the main purpose of volatile for a DMA buffer it to block incorrect optimizations (and prefetch etc), and if that is the only purpose of volatile, it is likely safe to "cast away" once the buffer is filled up.

Comment: Well, the instructions before the call to `call_external_interface` don't modify the data so it's wouldn't make any difference. Those instructions only act as a gate. The call won't execute until the condition is fulfilled, and that's that. There's no way to "reorder" anything here. Yes, the CPU will likely attempt speculative execution, with no ill effects other than possible security implications. But you probably don't worry about that.

Comment: Is `a` a pointer to a single integer, or to an array of them? If it's a pointer to an array, then all bets are off not because of out of order execution, but because of you possibly not being sure whether all of the array has been made valid. All you check is that one value is "valid". How do you know that the rest is valid, then? And if it's just a single value: `call_external_interface` shouldn't be taking any pointers. It should take an integer value, and if it wishes to modify it - it should return the new value. No `volatile` enters the picture then for the external interface.

Comment: It seems to me that there is no scope for a compiler to optimise this code in any way if `a` weren't volatile - unless `suspect()` is in fact a macro rather than a function call.

Answer (score 1):

The C Standard invites implementations to offer `volatile` semantics that are as strong or as weak as will best serve their customers (it explicitly regards such semantics as "implementation-defined").  MSVC has historically used semantics that are strong enough to be useful for a wide range of purposes (and were later recognized as useful by the designers of languages like Java or C#), and still has options to use that behavior.  Under MSVC semantics, this code would be expected to behave usefully.

Unfortunately, the Standard provides no means by which a programmer can indicate that operations involving non-qualified lvalues must not be reordered across accesses to `volatile`-qualified lvalues, and some compilers place a higher priority on the efficiency of code which can get by with weak semantics (freely reordering non-volatile accesses across `volatile` accesses), than on maximizing compatiblity with code written for a wide range of tasks (treating `volatile` accesses as though they were calls to opaque functions, or treating reads and writes as having acquire/release semantics).

Nothing in the C Standard would forbid an implementation from reordering non-volatile-qualified reads of `*a` that are performed by `call_external_interface` ahead of the `volatile` reads of `*a` performed by `foo`.  If `foo` were called within a loop, it's plausible that a "clever" compiler might hoist all of the accesses to `*a` that occur within `call_external_interface` so that they just occur once, rather than being repeated on every iteration through the loop.  The only way to make the code work reliably is to invoke a macro `COMPILER_ORDERING_BARRIER` between the volatile accesses to `*a` and any non-qualified accesses, and require that whoever is building the program define the macro in a fashion appropriate for the compiler being used.  Note that in a case like this there would be no need to insert a hardware memory barrier, and some compilers like MSVC would be able to process the code usefully without requiring any compiler-specific syntax, but other compilers like gcc or clang, so far as I can tell, have no optimizations options other than `-O0` that would result in them processing the code using MSVC-compatible semantics.

Comment: Aren't function calls sequence points?  And accessed can't be reordered across sequence points?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: As far as the Standard is concerned, a compiler can do anything it wants if any storage location which is ever accessed without a `volatile` qualifier is modified by means outside the compiler's control.  The language would have been largely useless for OS development on implementations which didn't offer some means of limiting the reach of such restrictions (one of the major purposes of a mutex is to allow threads to coordinate access to "ordinary" objects, and acquire-release `volatile` semantics are sufficient to implement a mutex, but clang/gcc-style `volatile` isn't).

Answer (score 0):

It's not so clear, what your `volatile int *a` is actually pointing too (the DMA TCD or the memory, where the data is transfered too by the DMA defined in the TCD.DESTADDR), and who is calling foo().

If there is a DMA transfer, you should rather react on a DMA event (e.g the ISR of major loop finished) to process the data, instead of the content transfered by the DMA. Doesn't make much sense to look at a content of an unfinished DMA transfer.

Answer (score 0):

> The assumption is that the "volatile" needed only until the buffer is
>   filled by the external resource, so the memory location is checked
>   twice whether the data is available or not ( and instructions are not
>   discarded since it is declared volatile).
>
> The assumption is also that once the buffer is available, it is just
>   processed internally, so the volatile can be discarded.

Those assumptions are not supported by the semantics defined by the C language specification.  They might or might not hold for any particular implementation, but if you intend to rely on the details of your C implementation then you need to find a way to determine *with certainty* what guarantees that implementation provides, beyond the language spec, that you can rely upon.  Unsupported assumptions get people into trouble.

> Can i be sure that the "call_external_interface" is called only after
>   executing the instructions coded before it?

In general, nothing in the C specification prevents other operations being reordered around volatile accesses, or otherwise optimized, as long as the observable behavior (including the pattern of volatile accesses) is unchanged.  In particular, if the `suspend()` function has no side effects on the execution environment, and the compiler has a way to know that, then the call to it might be omitted.

Supposing that the compiler cannot prove the call to `call_external_interface()` to be without side effects on the environment, however, the first read of `*a` will definitely be performed first.  If the result of that read so indicates then the second read also will be performed.  The function will return -1 without calling `call_external_interface()` if the second read is performed and its result does not test valid per whatever condition is expressed in the `if` statement.  All that is required in order to manifest the externally observable behavior described by your code.

> Do i need an explicit
>   memory barrier?

I don't see what you think would be gained.

> Any other remarks on how to make this code safe?

It depends on what you mean by "safe", and, in that light, on what the `suspend()` and `call_external_interface()` functions do.  However, casts have mildly bad code smell in general, and casting away the type qualifiers of pointer targets downright stinks.  If `call_external_interface()` does not accept (pointers to) volatile data and cannot be modified to do so, then the safest solution would be for `foo()` to read the volatile data and buffer it in non-volatile storage for `call_external_interface()` to use.

Alternatively, it may be that C is too high-level a language for the details you want to express.  You could consider rewriting `foo()` in assembly to have finer control over exactly how and when memory is accessed.

Answer (score -1):

it is a very bad idea in many cases and we should avoid it. Examples

```
void foo(volatile int *p)
{
    while(*p != 10);
}

void bar(int *p)
{
    while(*p != 10);
}

int goo(volatile int *p)
{
    foo(p);
}

int goo1(volatile int *p)
{
    bar((int *)p);
}

foo:
.L2:
        ldr     r3, [r0]
        cmp     r3, #10
        bne     .L2
        bx      lr
bar:
        ldr     r3, [r0]
        cmp     r3, #10
        bxeq    lr
.L8:
        b       .L8
goo:
.L10:
        ldr     r3, [r0]
        cmp     r3, #10
        bne     .L10
        bx      lr
goo1:
        ldr     r3, [r0]
        cmp     r3, #10
        bxeq    lr
.L15:
        b       .L15
```

in above example without the volatile the program ends in the dead loop.

or

```
void delay(unsigned delay)
{
    while(delay--);
}

int foo(int *a)
{
    int x = *a;
    delay(1000);
    return x + *a;
}

int bar(volatile int *a)
{
    int x = *a;
    delay(1000);
    return x + *a;
}

int goo(volatile int *a)
{
    return foo((int *)a);
}

int goo1(volatile int *a)
{
    return bar(a);
}

delay:
        cmp     r0, #0
        sub     r0, r0, #1
        bxeq    lr
.L3:
        subs    r0, r0, #1
        bxcc    lr
        subs    r0, r0, #1
        bxcc    lr
        b       .L3
foo:
        mov     r3, #1000
        ldr     r0, [r0]
.L10:
        subs    r3, r3, #1
        bne     .L10
        lsl     r0, r0, #1
        bx      lr
bar:
        mov     r3, #1000
        ldr     r2, [r0]
.L13:
        subs    r3, r3, #1
        bne     .L13
        ldr     r0, [r0]
        add     r0, r0, r2
        bx      lr
goo:
        mov     r3, #1000
        ldr     r0, [r0]
.L16:
        subs    r3, r3, #1
        bne     .L16
        lsl     r0, r0, #1
        bx      lr
goo1:
        mov     r3, #1000
        ldr     r2, [r0]
.L19:
        subs    r3, r3, #1
        bne     .L19
        ldr     r0, [r0]
        add     r0, r2, r0
        bx      lr
```

in this example without volatile the object is read only one time - but it could be changed by the DMA in the background.

Comment: Not sure, but one gripe I'd have: the result is only "self-explanatory" to those who already know the answer. There's nothing "self-explanatory" about what you wrote. You're writing the answer for a slightly lost human, not for interpretation by a CPU (aided by an assembler).